# Unmarshalling Error Jaxb - "Class does not have a default no arg constructor" while having a default no args constructor

Tags: java, xml, constructor, jaxb

I'm trying to unmarshal the following XML but getting an exception: "1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions EntityVersionInfo does not have a no-arg default constructor." despite actually having a no args constructor. What am I missing?

XML:

```xml
<topLevelObject>
  <entityVersionInfo>
        <id>111111</id>
        <version>1</version>
  </entityVersionInfo>
</topLevelObject>
```

Entities in Java with Annotations:

TopLevelObject:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "topLevelObject")

public class TopLevelObject {

    @XmlElement(name = "entityVersionInfo")
    private EntityVersionInfo versionInfo;

    public TopLevelObject() {
        //no args constructor
    }

    //GETTERS AND SETTERS HERE...
}
```

EntityVersionInfo:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "entityVersionInfo")

public class EntityVersionInfo {
    @XmlElement(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @XmlElement(name = "version")
    private String version;

    public EntityVersionInfo() {
        //no arg constructor
    }

    //GETTERS AND SETTERS
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this to EntityVersionInfo

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "EntityVersionInfo [id=" + id + ", version=" + version + "]";
}
```

Adding this to TopLevelObject

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "TopLevelObject [versionInfo=" + versionInfo + "]";
}
```

Running this test I get:

```
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(TopLevelObject.class);
    Unmarshaller u = context.createUnmarshaller();

    Reader reader = new StringReader(
            "<topLevelObject>\r\n" + 
            "  <entityVersionInfo>\r\n" + 
            "        <id>111111</id>\r\n" + 
            "        <version>1</version>\r\n" + 
            "  </entityVersionInfo>\r\n" + 
            "</topLevelObject>");
    Object o = u.unmarshal(new InputSource(reader ));
    System.out.println(o);
```

I get :

```
TopLevelObject [versionInfo=EntityVersionInfo [id=111111, version=1]]
```

So your *entity* code is good, maybe you have more then one EntityVersionInfo  class in your project or something else, but entities are good.

Comment: Whelp... this is embarrassing. Turns out I had another EntityVersionInfo class in my project. Thanks!

Comment: Nothing to be ashamed of, sometimes the obvious things are the most difficult to find.